# Azure User-Assigned Managed Identity for Sequalize ORM via Tedious

Tags: sequelize.js, azure-identity

There is plenty of documentation out there for [npm @azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity) style connection to SQL. Also the [Microsoft video on how Managed Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview) is great at explaining how managed identities is possible across more of the Azure stack is fundamentally strong. From this expansion of the managed identity stack increase we want to upgrade all our Node.js Azure App Services to use Managed Identities.

Currently our connection to Azure SQL is using Sequalize ORM via tedious and works great with SQL Server Credentials.

I am struggling to even find documentation if:

1. this upgrade is possible in sequalize to use a User-Assigned Managed Identity
2. if possible the syntax construction

I do not have any code attempts to show as my concern is becoming #1 at the moment. Naturally I tried a bunch of different approaches regarding #2.